# How proper enable extension=imagick.so on Google Cloud

Tags: php, wordpress, google-cloud-platform

I have a VM with Wordpress (click to deploy) on Google Cloud and need extension "**ImageMagick**".

According to this article:
https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/php7/runtime#php-7.4-beta

> Dynamically loadable extensions
> The following extensions are dynamically loadable by configuring php.ini:
> Memcached, gRPC, protobuf, MongoDB, **ImageMagick**, OpenCensus, PHPRedis

Add the line: `"extension=imagick.so"` on `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/php.ini`
and: `sudo service apache2 restart`

But stay dont working...

This my `php -m` :

```
tdias@universidade-bordado-vm:/etc/php/7.4/apache2$ php -m
[PHP Modules]
calendar
Core
ctype
curl
date
dom
exif
FFI
fileinfo
filter
ftp
gd
gettext
hash
iconv
json
libxml
mbstring
mysqli
mysqlnd
openssl
pcntl
pcre
PDO
pdo_mysql
Phar
posix
readline
Reflection
session
shmop
SimpleXML
sockets
sodium
SPL
standard
sysvmsg
sysvsem
sysvshm
tokenizer
xml
xmlreader
xmlwriter
xsl
Zend OPcache
zlib
[Zend Modules]
Zend OPcache
```

Comment: Are you sure the apache did restart? If the line was added correctly in the extensions section it should work, my guess is the service didn't restart and the php is still the old one.

Comment: @yomisimie yes... is so strange... i restart so much times. Trying to close and open ssh... and nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is, Google Cloud require you install before add extesion on php-ini, just run:

```
sudo apt-get install php-imagick
```

After you can enable  on `phph.ini`

```
"extension=imagick.so"
```

Last, just restar apache:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```

Comment: Thank you!. May need to confirm that the install location is correct. For example on my server the php had multiple version so I had to specify: sudo apt-get install php7.4-imagick